# can one remote execute queries from within t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

First the raw question:

Given that there are 2 DBs: DB1 and DB2. Can I, being connected to DB1, perform a query on DB2 as if I'm logged on to DB2? 
So basically:

- I'm connected to DB1
- From within TSQL I somehow connect to DB2
- I perform the query locally (and wait)
- I close the connection and am back on DB1
- and I do the remainder of the query.

SO I know I can do interDB queries like: select * from DB2.somedb.dbo.sometable but this is not what I'm after.

Background:

Is have data sitting on 2 separate DB machines. I have to query the data in such a way as to combine data from tables on both machines.

I have tried lot's of scenarios and everytime it either runs very slow, or a query can't be done due to XML columns being present in one table or the other.

The solution which does work (although manually) is:

- log on to DB2 and do half of the query into some temp table
- copy the temptable over to DB1
- logon to db1 and perform the second part of the query.

perferably I want to make this all one script so I can automate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the `OPENQUERY` function in SQL Server:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'OracleSvr', 
   'Oracle 7.3', 
   'MSDAORA', 
   'ORCLDB'
GO
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(OracleSvr, 'SELECT name, id FROM joe.titles') 
GO
```

Or even the `OPENROWSET` function:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Seattle1;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'SELECT GroupName, Name, DepartmentID
      FROM AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Department
      ORDER BY GroupName, Name') AS a;
```

Use SQL Server books online for more detail or try out your *googlefu*

Comment: Not sure if this will work with native XML columns, you may need to use a view over the table that shreads out the interesting data from the table into native columns.

Comment: Also, with linked SQL Servers, you can just issue queries like: SELECT * FROM SERVER1.database.dbo.tablename INNER JOIN SERVER2.database.dbo.tablename ON... etc. etc.

Comment: @matt gibson: The linked servers has limitations, like tables containing XML-columns, and queries being exceptionally slow in some cases

Comment: Dependening on your setup and requirements, it may just be better to set up a SSIS package to copy the data across to the same server/database and use that in "not real time" mode.

Answer (score 1):

First, YOU HAVE to link the two SQL Servers (SQL1 and SQL2). You need to create a link server on SQL1 towards SQL2 with a valid login having proper rights on the remote database. More info about this on MSDN - [How to create a link server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998%28BTS.70%29.aspx)

Once you created the linked server you should be able to use both linked server functionality as well as openquery function.

**The query executed from SQL1 using directly Linked server** (Executes the specified pass-through query through the network from SQL1 to SQL2- more I/O)

```
select * from [LINKED_SERVER_SQL2].[DATABASE_NAME].dbo.[TABLE_NAME]
```

**The query executed using Openquery** (Executes the specified pass-through query on the given linked server - lest I/O)

```
select * from openquery (LINKED_SERVER_SQL2, 'select * from [DATABASE_NAME].dbo.[TABLE_NAME]')
```

Also, the answer for the xml columns particularity can be found at [this pos](http://irina2dose.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/sql-server-%E2%80%93-fix-error-msg-9514-level-16-state-1-line-1-xml-data-typ/)t, I wrote a blog couple of days ago about the same issue I found